# give 30s delay when password not match

Tags: android, security, password-protection

In my application I want to give 30 sec delay  when user give multiple wrong password but the problem is how can I count the number of failure attempt and after that how can I create 30 sec delay on my app please help.

Comment: Standard SO question:"What have you tried so far?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a private variable called passwordfailedcount in your private variables.

```
int passwordfailedcount = 0;
```

Also create one for your password failed limit...

```
int passwordfailedlimit = 5;
```

We should also declare a handler to (this will hadle the 30 second delay) this should be a private variable too...

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

Every time the user enters the wrong password exectute have code like this:

```
passwordfailedcount++;
        if (passwordfailedcount >= passwordfailedlimit)
        {
            //disable all your text boxes, display a toast or alert, whatever you fancy...
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // re enable all your buttons and set failed count back to 0
                    passwordfailedcount = 0;
                }
            }, 30000);
        }
```